# Trouble with mod C

Tags: c, math, division

I just started doing codeforces problems, I started with problem 4-A (Watermelon), in which given an int x number of kilos the program will print "YES" if when you split the watermelon in two halves, each one has an even number of kilos, if not "NO".
My problem here is that I get "YES" when the input is 5, and it should be "NO"
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int x) {
    if((x/2) % 2 == 0) {
        printf("YES");
    }else {
        printf("NO");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351925/why-does-2-mod-4-2 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194629/how-is-3-modulo-5-3 http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/17383/

Comment: Er... Any how exactly do you plan to pass your argument to that `main` function of yours? How does that `5` get there? How do you set that `x` to `5`?

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised at the answers that claim to simply perform `x%2 == 0` exclusively as the test. That will *not* do what that question asks for. The melon must be (a) an even number of kilos, *and* (b) weight *more* than 2 kilos outright. Any even number greater than 2 can be split into two even numbers (and often in multiple partition configurations).

Comment: `(x/2) % 2` is equivalent to `x & 0x2`. You want divisibility by 4, use `x % 4` instead

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc divisibility by four won't cut it either. 10 is a valid weight for the problem. It can be split into two pieces, 6 and 4, both of which are even numbers. Nothing in the problem says the split must be the *same* number for *both* pieces. It would probably have been handy had the OP [linked the original question](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/4/A) in the post. Or are you saying it should be `(x/4) % 2` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig as I read "split the watermelon in two halves" I thought that it's cut into 2 equal halves

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I would have thought so as well, but I've seen the problem before, and the phrasing in the question was somewhat weak. The answer, however, is as I described. Any even number larger than 2 will suffice as a valid source weight.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with `mod`, but with parameter passing.

The typical prototype for main is

```
int main(int argument_count, char *arg_list[], ...);
```

Calling `my_exe 5` will set the first parameter `x` (argument_count) as 2, and the next *unused* parameter

```
arg_list[0] = "my_exe",  // the first (0th) argument is the executable name
arg_list[1] = "5"        // rest of parameters as arrays of chars
```

Calling `my_exe` without parameters sets `x = 1` giving `YES`

Also if the argument `x` is a character `'5'` with the decimal value of 53 (0x35), the result is `YES`. This would be rather unconventional behavior, but definitely possible within some undisclosed IDE or coding framework.

Comment: Try changing `printf("YES");` to `printf("YES %d", x);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if((x/2) % 2 == 0)
```

This condition is why you get `yes` for `5` as `5/2` is `2`(as it is int) and `2%2` is `0`.

just this will work -

```
if(x%2==0)
```

Comment: he wants divisibility by 4, not 2, as after dividing by 2 it's still an even number

Answer (score 0):

Since the argument is an int then the division the remainder will be left. That is: 5 / 2 will result in a 2. Then that 2 mod 2 will give you a zero. What you should dp is to just put x % 2 inside the 'if' statement. So, with that 5 % 2 will give you a '1' which is thenn different to zero

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing operation with integers, `(5/2)=2`, Hence you are getting "YES" as the output.
Try this code

```
int main (int x) {
    if(x % 4 == 0) {
        printf("YES");
    }else {
        printf("NO");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the condition is true, it will mean that the halves are even as well.